# Why is an instance variable avoided in template (view file)?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Why is it not good to use an instance variable in a template while showing data on the browser?

Ex:
**Controller**

```
def show_data
 @user = User.all
end
```

**show_data.js.erb**

```
$('#popup_div').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'view_form', :user => @user) %>");
```

**_view_form.html.erb**

```
<%= user.name %>
```

What is `user`? We can call an instance (`@user`) in the template like:

```
<%= @user.name %>
```

What is the difference between `<%= user.name %>` and `<%= @user.name %>`? Why are we doing `:user => @user`?

Comment: `user` should be defined somewhere in `view_form.html.erb`, show us full code.

Comment: yes it is define in show_data.js.erb

Comment: but instead of making it local i can use direct instance at template so why we usually making it local symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing variables to partials is better than using instance variables in many ways. One reason is that partials can be used from any controller (DRY principle), and thus you can render `view_form` later from another controller when you might not have `@user` defined or defined it differently.